# Deploying Flex\ColdFusion to Web Server

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, flash-builder

I'm developing a mobile application using Flash Builder. It is connected to a remote MySQL database and ColdFusion which is installed on my computer.

The program runs smoothly in the debugger. However, when I tried to run it on the actual device using USB, I got the following message:

> " the project is currently configured to access data services from
>   local url that cannot be accessed from your device. Before running the
>   application on device, you should deploy data services to server that
>   your device can access.  "

I don't know what I am supposed to do to make it work on the device.

Comment: what is the URL for your service?  127.0.0.1?  localhost?  Or do you have a domain set up?  If you have a domain; is it set up in a local hosts file or do you have a DNS Service?

Comment: Then that is your problem.  Localhost always refers to the current machine.  When you move your code to the device; the current machine is your device--not the computer.  I assume you do not have CF setup on your mobile device.  You'll need to move to a formal domain name.  The message you quoted is actually fairly complete about what you have to do.

Comment: this is photo for my setting on flash builder http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/9503/jx0a.jpg  what server do you suggest i have to get?

Comment: What you're asking for is way to long to explain in a comment. But, I would expect it to be basic knowledge for a web developer. Bsaically, go to a domain registar, like namecheap and register a domain. Then you can use their DNS services to point to the public IP address of your machine. Then you'll need to install Apache or IIS and set up the web site. Then you'll need to set up ColdFusion to speak to that web server. then modify your Flex code to point to your domain name instead of localhost.

Comment: When both devices are in your own network, create a DNS entry/modify the hosts-file/access your computer with its hostname

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mobile App Using Remote Web Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770166/mobile-app-using-remote-web-server)